# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Aframara Website\images

Tags: html, css, npm, postcss, parceljs

I have been trying to remove unused CSS from the `style.css` and in `bootstrap.min.css` in my website that is in development mode. Am using PostCSS & Parcel to do this.

So I installed both PostCSS and Parcel and then created a `postcss.config.js`.

The `postcss.config.js` has the following code

`postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    Plugins:[
        require("postcss-uncss")({
            html:[
             '/index.html'
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```

When I run `parcel index.html` this error keeps showing up

G:\Aframara Website\images\about\ us.jpg: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Aframara Website\images\about\ us.jpg'

I have 7 Html files and the `style.css` as mentioned earlier together with `bootstrap.min.css`.

So I would like to reduce the size of all the two files. I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX7McYRGJ8o&t=325s) and did exactly as he said. If anyone has another way I will appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it, I Installed `npm i -g purgecss`

Then I created a folder with the title 'purged' at the root of my website.

I ran this command

```
purgecss --css *.css **/*.css --content *.html *.js --output purged
```

What this command did it created the two files i.e `style.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` in the folder purged.

Then I changed the css styles URL from `css/bootstrap.min.css` to `purged/bootstrap.min.css` and `css/style.css` to `purged/style.css`

The `*.js` is to check to see if you have any styles dynamically generated in javascript. You can leave it if you want.

The size of my two files `bootstrap.min.css` and `style.css` were reduced significantly.